# How to use CASE in order to alter data retrieved from database

Tags: sql, postgresql

Beginner in SQL, I am trying to use `CASE` to do some conditional operation.

I have a table called `MangaTable` which contains the details of some Manga (Comics) such as title, author etc. I am trying to `GROUP` the authors to see how many titles they have like this:

```
SELECT AUTHOR, COUNT(AUTHOR) FROM MANGATABLE GROUP BY AUTHOR
```

I got the data like this:

```
"Masashi Kishimoto" | 1
"Eiichiro Oda"      | 1
"Tsugumi Ohba"      | 1
"Kubo Tite"         | 2
```

But instead of numbers I want to display "Single" or "Multiple". 
I tried this:

```
SELECT AUTHOR, COUNT(AUTHOR) AS CAL, CASE WHEN CAL>1 THEN 'MULTIPLE' ELSE 'SINGLE' END FROM MANGATABLE GROUP BY AUTHOR
```

But I am getting an Error: `column "cal" does not exist`

Please advice.

Comment: CASE WHEN COUNT(AUTHOR)?

Comment: Note that when you really *need* to re-use a result you can do so by generating it in a common table expression (`WITH` expression). It's often not worth the cost, but when the calculation you need to reference multiple times are slow and expensive there are times it can be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `ALIAS` that is created on the same level of the query,

```
SELECT AUTHOR, COUNT(AUTHOR) AS CAL, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(AUTHOR)>1 THEN 'MULTIPLE' ELSE 'SINGLE' END 
FROM MANGATABLE 
GROUP BY AUTHOR
```

The order of operation is as follows:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

The alias is create on the `SELECT` clause that is why you cannot use it.

Comment: very nicely explained...Thanks... +1

Comment: He can use alias on a temporary table.

Comment: @DamienJoe of course he can I didn't say anything about *temporary* table though `:)`

Comment: @JW my bad sorry & your answer is great in every aspect.

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to an expression in the select list by alias within the select list - it will work if you change it to:

```
SELECT AUTHOR, 
       COUNT(AUTHOR) AS CAL, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(AUTHOR)>1 THEN 'MULTIPLE' ELSE 'SINGLE' END AS AUTHOR_TYPE
FROM MANGATABLE
GROUP BY AUTHOR
```

It's unfortunate to have to repeat the expression again - it's one of the deficiencies of SQL.

You can sometimes avoid this using the [WITH](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-with.html) expression to factor common parts out.

(Yes, you can change the column heading by specifying an alias for the case expression - I've added that in.)

Comment: Thanks....works fine...the header for multiple or single appears as `CASE` can I change the header also?

Answer (score 0):

You should only need a small change see below

```
SELECT 
    AUTHOR, 
    COUNT(AUTHOR) AS CAL, 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(AUTHOR) THEN 'MULTIPLE' ELSE 'SINGLE' END     
FROM MANGATABLE GROUP BY AUTHOR
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a temporary table

```
SELECT CASE z.CAL WHEN 1 THEN 'MULTIPLE' ELSE 'SINGLE' END FROM (SELECT AUTHOR, 
COUNT(AUTHOR) AS CAL  FROM MANGATABLE GROUP BY AUTHOR) as z
```

**Correction**

```
    SELECT (CASE WHEN z.CAL > 1 THEN 'MULTIPLE' ELSE 'SINGLE' END) as test FROM (SELECT AUTHOR, 
COUNT(AUTHOR) AS CAL  FROM MANGATABLE GROUP BY AUTHOR) as z
```